# Change c++ standard library on Android in bazel

Tags: c++11, android-ndk, bazel

I'm building a C++11 program that works on osX, but the build for android fails with "error: 'round' is not a member of 'std'".

This is a known problem, associated with the gnustl standard library (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54418), and the current best workaround seems to be to link against LLVM libc++.

How to do so is documented [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html) for Android Studio or cmake, but I cannot find any documentation for how to do the same with bazel, if it is possible.

Comment: I understand that, but waiting for fixes to gnustl to trickle down isn't really a viable solution.

Comment: I don't think so. C++11 is enabled, the issue is that the default standard library does not properly support it.

Further, this is a question about Bazel, that question is answered with reference to Gradle/Android Studio. (As in my second link, changing the stl in Gradle is documented.)

Answer (score 0):

A partial answer:
if just building an android static library, the command line call has to specify crosstool_top. This can be set to a specific toolchain using something like --crosstool_top=@androidndk//:toolchain-libcpp.

Options can be found in external/androidndk/BUILD in the directory generated by bazel.

However, if building the library as part of an android application, the crosstool would be inferred. I don't know whether the same approach works, or if not what the answer would be.

Comment: `--crosstool_top=@androidndk//:toolchain-libcpp` will change the entire target configuration to use the android crosstool, which may still work, but you can use `--android_crosstool_top` instead to use the android crosstool for dependencies of `android_binary` rules